# How to parse grid view item id to SQLite WHERE claus?

Tags: android, sqlite

When a user click on an item I need to get the item id and send it to list view activity. But the list view is populated from a pre-populated SQLite db and items should retrive based on item id of grid view.

Example : If user click item 1 (Bank icon) on first activity , list view should retrieve data of bank names.

This is my gridview onItem click code.

```
       grid.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));

    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContactView.class);
            intent.putExtra("catid", id);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });


}
```

This is my code to retrieve list items on DB Access class.

```
    public List<String> getQuotes() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Long value;
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        value = bundle.getLong("catid");
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT org_name FROM org_name WHERE category_id='value'", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
            cursor.moveToNext();
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Full code of Custom Grid View Adapter.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

class ViewHolder{
    ImageView myCategories;
    ViewHolder(View v){
        myCategories = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.myCat);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View row =view;
    ViewHolder holder=null;

    if(row==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, viewGroup, false);
        holder=new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    Categories temp= list.get(i);
    holder.myCategories.setImageResource(temp.imgId);

    return row;    }


class Categories{
    int imgId;
    String categoryName;

    Categories(int imgId,String categoryName){
        this.imgId=imgId;
        this.categoryName=categoryName;
    }

}

Context context;
ArrayList<Categories> list;

CustomAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
    list=new ArrayList<Categories>();

    Resources res=context.getResources();
    String[] tempCategoryNames= res.getStringArray(R.array.category_array);

    int [] categoryImages={R.drawable.bank,R.drawable.education,R.drawable.fashion,R.drawable.hospitals,R.drawable.hotels,R.drawable.restaurant,R.drawable.retail,R.drawable.transport};

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        Categories tempHello = new Categories(categoryImages[i],tempCategoryNames[i]);
        list.add(tempHello);

    }
    // res.getStringArray(R.array.categories);

}

}
```

Fullcode of GridView Activity on MainActivity class

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);


   toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


//    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, categories, imageId);

   grid.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));

    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContactView.class);
            intent.putExtra("catid", id);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });


}
```

Comment: instead of id ,use position to get values from db :)

Comment: please add complete code of gridview acitivity and custom adapter

Comment: what is the value of `catid` passed to your `Intent`?

Comment: @USKMobility - Updated

Comment: @pskink - Grid item selected by the user.

Comment: what is the **value** of `catid` passed to your `Intent`? just use `Log.d`

Comment: Change query by this _"SELECT org_name FROM org_name WHERE category_id="+" ' " + value+" ' ";_

Answer (score 0):

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

> long id: The row id of the item that was clicked.

And also: `SELECT org_name FROM org_name WHERE category_id='value'` is invalid. value in your code is string "value", it is not value of catid.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited the code. But still it's not working.

Comment: Are you want to pass catelogy id to second screen?

Comment: You have to ensure 2 things: 1: Pass extract catid, 2: got this catid in second screen. After that, read this guide to know how to query data: http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: This is my answer for your question 'Are you want to pass catelogy id to second screen? '

What I want is when user clicks item 1 I want to query details about that item. For that in DB I created a category id field and assign values 1-8. Then I'm getting the item click id from user and equal that value to category id value here. Is that wrong ?

Comment: Put to intent position instead of id

Comment: I tried with position. But it gives an error. Application stopped.

Comment: @venura did you `Log.d` the id passed to your `Intent`?

Comment: @pskink - I added    Log.i("testTag","Intent parse"); after startActivity. Hope it'sc correct. This is what I got.

04-24 07:40:38.434    1078-1078/? I/SQLiteAssetHelper﹕ successfully opened database hellosl.db_upgrade_1-7.db
04-24 07:40:38.434    1078-1078/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa623e288)
04-24 07:40:38.434    1078-1078/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: @venura ok, seems that you dont really care about getting your issue to be solved

Comment: @pskink - Why is that ? I'm still a beginner. Please help

Comment: @venura i asked you three times: what is the **VALUE** of id passed to your second activity? and you ignored that 3 times

Comment: @pskink- Very sorry. When user clicks item I want to pass the clicked item id. In log.d how do I check that? I added log.i after startactivty method.

Comment: get item id by get item from your list item by position